# ImportError: No module named cert

Tags: python-2.7

OS: Fedora 20
Python : 2.7.9

I Installed "pki" using :  **pip install pki**

When I do a **import pki.cert**, I get "ImportError: No module named cert "

Under /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pki
     I don't see a cert.py

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Nope. I have already installed **swig-3.0.5-6.fc20.x86_64**

Answer (score 0):

Clone pki from:

git clone http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/pki.git

```
(We can see cert.py is getting added)
```

Execute setup.py